# Can I do on my robot.urdf in RViz without real hardware access? (Simulation mode only)

Tags: rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not sure that I can do simulation mode first without real hardware access.
If yes, How to do that?

I appreciate any help and pointers in any direction.

Thanks. :

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/246729/can-i-do-on-my-robot.urdf-in-rviz-without-real-hardware-access?-(simulation-mode-only)/) by [Chucolate](https://answers.ros.org/users/28340/chucolate/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-10-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

First (and slightly pedantic, but important): RViz is *not* a simulator. It's a data(flow) visualisation tool.

If you want a full dynamic simulation of a robot (ie: including physics), you could use [Gazebo](http://gazebosim.org/), [V-REP](http://www.coppeliarobotics.com) or any other simulator. You only need a model of your robot for that (kinematics, dynamics, geometry, etc).

Your ROS nodes can treat the simulated robot as a real robot, and RViz can visualise data coming from the simulator just as it would data coming from a real robot. There isn't really a difference.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-10-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Chucolate](https://answers.ros.org/users/28340/chucolate/) on 2016-10-29**:
It means that I need to work simulator on Gazebo first and then use simulator data from Gazebo for RViz right?

Big thanks.